# How to create a generate code section in our site?

Tags: php, html, php-5.3

I have to give the Html code of my order form to third parties. Once they register and payed they can copy and paste the html code from my site to their own site. but the date will be saved in my site with the reference of the reseller. How can I implement this kind of a section in my website. any body can help me. I am using php5 and mysql.

Comment: bigner - without being critical here. if you're taking paid clients into your 'service' but are unaware of the mechanism to do the above are you sure you should be doing it via a web page?? I'm just 'scared' you could have a technical slip with your clients' details...

no offence intended, just an observation from the content of your question.

Comment: @jim what you're trying to say is "tell us the website, so i can add it to the list of sites not to order from" ;)

Comment: kieran - i'm far too discreet to suggest that :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="http://example.com/" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="associate_id" value="some-identifier">
```